# MVC: Displaying dynamic forms based on URL arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jscript.net, dynamicform

I am trying to generate content within a view based on a URL parameter.

For example:

- 10 companies, 30 users each
- A user from company Google clicks a distributed icon that opens
  www.****tickets.com/ticket/?c=Google
- A custom ticketing page with textboxes, dropdownlists with
  'Google-specific' categories and the Google logo is displayed.
- All of this data will be handled by a common controller

I have lots of plans for this site, but this is step #1.  I am pretty new to MVC, but I have a page propped up that has Users/Groups/Roles.  I'm unsure if there would be a better way to implement this, such as Javascript.

EDIT: It looks like [MVC Dynamic Forms](http://mvcdynamicforms.codeplex.com/) could be useful for this application. Researching it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller method for handling the URL /ticket should accept an optional parameter c. This will then automatically be populated by the value in the querystring. You can then hold this in a model and pass it into the view.

The code will be something like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Ticket(string c = null)
{
    //Get some data based on c
    var model = new TicketModel
    { 
        Company = c, 
        SomeDropdownValues = StuffYouReadFromTheDbUsingParameterC,
        LogoPath = PathYouHaveCalculatedUsingParameterC
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

If you don't know how to use a model within a view look up the term "model binding". [This article](http://www.edandersen.com/2013/05/28/asp-net-mvc-basics-part-1-view-model-binding/) explains it clearly.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I will look into that article.  Will I need to use partial views if not all companies use all of the fields, or can I just make those not required?

Comment: No, you could just not display those fields using `if` statements based on values in the model.